# Change datepicker display format (php)

Tags: php

how can i change the display format of date picker?

```
<tr>
  <td width="30%"><label>Date Registered</label</td>
  <td >'.$row["dateRegistered_vehicle"].'</td>
</tr>
```

using the date attributes, the data would be displayed as 2017/08/21.
how can i change this to 21/08/2017?

ive used datepicker in the insert form and does show the value as i want. but when i want to display the date in a table(html), the date come out as 2017/02/21 instead of 21/02/2017.

Comment: This sounds more like a datepicker configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date built in method of php. 
These websites are helpful:

1) http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

2) https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Anyways here is the answer to your question.

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["dateRegistered_vehicle"]));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This how you will change the date format

```
<?php
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row["dateRegistered_vehicle"]));
?>
```

also DatePicker format

```
<script>
$('#date_field').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
</script>
```